# Deal with circular standard deviation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, standard-deviation, data-analysis

I have a sensor that gives me a direction of the target in degrees with a certain standard deviation and I use a circular probability density function (PDF) to represent probable locations for the target. For example if the sensor is in `[20 20]` and the measurement is `45` degrees with `3` degrees of std, I get something like this,

[image]

I multiply the PDF of the measurements when sensor is in three or four different locations and I get almost an accurate estimate of the target position. My problem is the calculation of CEP (Circular Error Probability) or even other types of position accuracy measures. Table below has the definition,

[image]

As you can see they all have the variance in the direction of `x` and `y` but I only have one variance in the form of square degrees. So can I somehow convert this variance? or am I missing some obvious facts?

Comment: "I multiply the PDF of the measurements when sensor is in three or four different locations and I get almost an accurate estimate of the target position." Do you mean by this you are calculating the maximum likelihood estimate of the position given the observations?

Comment: @muaddib, I'm not familiar with ML but multiplying the PDFs and selecting the location of maximum value gives a good estimation.

Comment: Then it does sound like you are using MLE, and you are asking what is the error in your maximum likelihood estimate, with those values in the table being different measures of error.  Maybe this thread would be helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88481/what-is-meant-by-the-standard-error-of-a-maximum-likelihood-estimate